# How to configure work laptop - Can't write viminfo error

Tags: windows-7, vim

Lot's of related questions here.  This one is very appropriate:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851007/why-might-vim-think-that-home-is-the-u-drive

I installed vim in my user directory (not in Program Files) because I have write privileges in the user directory.  When I fire up a command prompt `%HOMEDRIVE%` is set to H:\ which is our network drive.

When I start vim and then quit I get the error:

```
E138: can't write H:\_viminfo!
```

If in the command prompt I set %HOMEDRIVE% to my userdirectory its fine.  However, in the normal dialog if I set the environment variable (either the user or the system) HOMEDRIVE to the userdirectory, it has no effect and HOMEDRIVE will remain as H:\

At this point I'm looking for help to either of the following questions:

1) Is there a vim configuration around this
2) Is there some other way to change the %HOMEDRIVE% variable if my system just seems to have it that way.

Comment: add `set viminfo=` in _vimrc file which tells vim not to store edit info. If you do like edit info, set to a writable directory of choice. You can also `:help viminfo` while in vim presuming its help got installed.

Comment: I installed into C:\Users\myusername\Programs\Vim.  `:version` displays the system rc file as `$VIM\vimrc` where `$Vim` is the just mentioned install directory.  To be save I put a vimrc and a _vimrc file in that directory (one was already there) and did as you mentioned but it did not make the error message go away.  setting `viminfo=` and `viminfo='some/writeable/dir` had no effect that I could discern in this vimrc file.  `$HOME` refers to `H:\` so that is not really an option

Comment: one of those takes precedence. Ideally, yours should be in your home directory. But remove the one you created, edit the original, and add at bottom. If so inclined, look for entries referring to home and change.

Comment: yes, I removed the one I added, open vim and did `:e $MYVIMRC` which was the correct system vimrc file.  I added your suggestion but it still had no effect on not writing the editinfo.  Oh well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a new work laptop running Windows 10.  Setting a user environment variable HOME to some directory fixed this behavior